# MYSQL - DATE_SUB and INTERVAL

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query in a script which is automatically recharging the customer based on order date - 1 month.

```
SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE orderdate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month)
```

The problem is that for months having more days than previous month, this query 
runs for every day more than previous day.

e.g

March is 2-3 days more than February, so the query will run 2-3 times for 28/29 feb.

28 march will run 28 feb (this is ok)

29 march will again fetch 28 feb (repetition)

30 march will again fetch 28 feb (repetition)

31 march will again fetch 28 feb (repetition)

How can i avoid repetitions

Comment: How about: `SELECT * FROM registrations WHERE orderdate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 year)`?

Comment: script runs everyday and it has to do things for same day last month

Comment: Maybe adding `IF` or `CASE` in the condition?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the compare out into its 3 individual parts, comparing the year and month values with one month earlier but not touching the day value. That way March 31 will translate to February 31, which cannot match anything.

```
SELECT *
FROM registrations
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  AND MONTH(orderdate) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  AND DAY(orderdate) = DAY(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the ugly way is fine:

```
WHERE orderdate = date( concat( year(curdate())
                              , '-'
                              , month(curdate())-1
                              , '-'
                              , day(curdate())
                              )
                      )
```

So invalid dates will be null and will not match.